# S3 Object ownership: Bucket Owner Enforced - documentation bug?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, acl

I recently ran into a "bug" where, even with `S3FullAccess`, I'd still get

```
An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

when running `aws s3api head-object --bucket cool-bucket --key my/key/to/file.png`.

After some research, it turned out that `my/key/to/file.png` was uploaded anonymously and thus I, an authenticated user, was not the object's rightful owner, thus denying me the HEAD request.

The solutions to that seemed to be either ACLs or changing "Object Ownership" to "ACLs disabled (Bucket owner enforced)".

[image: AWS console to set object ownership of S3 bucket]

This was indeed the solution so I tried changing my CloudFormation template to set Object Ownership to "Bucket Owner Enforced", [**but the documentation lies.**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-ownershipcontrolsrule.html)

Indeed, the doc only specifies that `Allowed values: ObjectWriter | BucketOwnerPreferred`, but when running `aws s3api get-bucket-ownership-controls --bucket bucketname` onto my manually tweaked bucket, I got the following JSON:

```json
{
    "OwnershipControls": {
        "Rules": [
            {
                "ObjectOwnership": "BucketOwnerEnforced"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Clearly showing that `BucketOwnerEnforced` is a valid and allowed value for the CloudFormation property `OwnershipControls.Rules.[].ObjectOwnership`. Nowhere else in the doc did I see a property allowing me to set Object Ownership to "Bucket Owner Enforced" and thus disabled the ACLs.

Why isn't that documented ? I thought CloudFormation doc was automatically generated and could be incomplete/outdated.

Comment: It looks like the documentation may not have been updated to include the brand new feature BucketOwnerEnforced, which was literally introduced yesterday at re:Invent 2021.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! You're right, I don't follow re:Invent really closely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a secretly allowed value to the property `OwnershipControls.Rules.[].ObjectOwnership` called `BucketOwnerEnforced`.

It can be used like this:

```yaml
  MyCoolBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: MyCoolBucket
      OwnershipControls:
        Rules:
          - ObjectOwnership: BucketOwnerEnforced
```

I tested and deployed this template on 2021-12-02 and CloudFormation didn't complain about it not being an "Allowed value".

Comment: I wouldn't call it 'secret'. It simply looks like the documentation hasn't been updated to reflect the brand new option (introduced yesterday).